# Datastage merge files

Tags: datastage

I need to merge 3 input files into 1 output file via datastage, may I know how to achieve this?

Background:
The 3 input files have different fields (layout)

example:

Input file A:  HDR123

Input file B:  000123

Input file C:  TRL003

Expected output:

HDR123

000123

TRL003

Comment: Thanks Michael, will have a try

Answer (score 0):

You can use the funnel stage for this but the data types and length need to match (similar to a union in SQL).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in datastage by defining two jobs:
Job-1. parallel job: sequential file -> sequential file
Job-2. sequence job: startloop activity -> job activity -> endloop activity

Define job-1 as follows:
source sequential file
Define job parameter, say #INPUT# and use this value as file name in the file path, say : /tmp/#INPUT#

i.e. input files are /tmp/A, /tmp/B and /tmp/C

target sequential file
Output file, say /tmp/out.txt
File update mode : Append

Define job-2 as follows:
start loop activity : Loop definition -> delimited values : A,B,C (Delimiter comma)

job activity: Job name = above job-1
Parameters : INPUT = StartLoop_Activity_0.$Counter

Now compile both job-1 and job-2
Run sequence job job-2.  You will expected result in /tmp/out.txt

Please note that, if you run the sequence job again, you will see the same contents appended again, so you need to make sure you have no file called /tmp/out.txt before running sequence job or it is empty.